# identifying categorical variables in a dataset

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, data-cleaning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a dataset with 150+ features, and I want to separate them as text, categories and numerics. The categorical and text variables are having the Object data type. How do we distinguish between a categorical and text variable? Is there any threshold value for the categorical variable?

Comment: There is no fixed threshold, it depends on how many categories you want to distinguish. Usually, this depends on the input data source (e.g. predefined values vs free form text) and will affect your features, depending on the encoding you choose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear distinction between categories and text. However, if you want to understand if a particular feature is `categorical` you can do a simple test.

e.g. if you are using `pandas`, you can use `value_counts()` / `unique()` for a feature. If the number of results are comparable to the size of the dataset, this is not a categorical field.

Similarly for numerics too.. But in numerics it may be `Ordinal`, meaning there is a clear ordering. e.g., size of t-shirts.